# How To Integrate Woocommerce With Piwik

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, matomo

Currently, I have setup tracking on my wordpress website using piwik. However, on top of that, I need to be able to track the e-commerce conversion and abandoned cart. I have managed to track the conversion manually but I have no idea on how do I replace the hardcoded values with the "woocommerce ordered products" values.

Here are what have I done so far:

1. Installed WP-Piwik
2. Installed WooCommerce Piwik integration
3. I created my custom javascript, called "piwik.js", and  I hardcoded the values to track e-commerce purchases.

   ```
   function addEcommerceItem() {
   // add the first product to the order
       _paq.push(['addEcommerceItem',
       "sku01", // (required) SKU: Product unique identifier
       "sku01Name", // (optional) Product name
       "productCategory", // (optional) Product category. You can also specify an array of up to 5 categories eg. ["Books", "New releases", "Biography"]
       60, // (recommended) Product price
       1 // (optional, default to 1) Product quantity
       ]);
       alert("e-Commerce item added!");
    };

    function trackEcommerceOrder() {       
       _paq.push(['trackEcommerceOrder',
       "A10000127", // (required) Unique Order ID
       35, // (required) Order Revenue grand total (includes tax, shipping, and subtracted discount)
       30, // (optional) Order sub total (excludes shipping)
       5.5, // (optional) Tax amount
       4.5, // (optional) Shipping amount
       false // (optional) Discount offered (set to false for unspecified parameter)
       ]);
     alert("item tracked!");
     };
   ```
4. On my Woocommerce, checkout page:

   ```
      [woocommerce_checkout]
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://myServerIP/mySite/piwik.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         addEcommerceItem(); 
         trackEcommerceOrder(); 
      </script>
   ```
5. And again, my question was how do I replace hardcoded values in `addEcommerceItem()` and `trackEcommerceOrder()` to reflect whatever products being purchased through my woocommerce site dynamically?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified 'piwik-woocommerce-integration' plugin -> 'class-wc-piwik-tracker.php'

1. Replaced `piwikTracker.addEcommerceItem()` and its implementation with:

   ```
   //add order
   _paq.push(['addEcommerceItem',
      "<?php echo esc_js( $_product->get_sku() ); ?>",
      "<?php echo esc_js( $item['name'] ); ?>",
      "<?php
         if ( isset( $_product->variation_data ) )
            echo esc_js( woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $_product->variation_data, true ) );
               ?>",
       <?php echo esc_js( $order->get_item_total( $item ) ); ?>,
       <?php echo esc_js( $item['qty'] ); ?>]);
   ```
2. Replaced `piwikTracker.trackEcommerceOrder()` and its implementation with:

   ```
   // Track order
   _paq.push(['trackEcommerceOrder',
      "<?php echo esc_js( $order->get_order_number() ); ?>",
       <?php echo esc_js( $order->get_total() ); ?>,
       false,
       <?php echo esc_js( $order->get_total_tax() ); ?>,
       <?php echo esc_js( $order->get_shipping() ); ?>,
       false
       ]);
       _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
   ```